# How to access element by id in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have table generated with dynamic ids like this one

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of createRange(seats.theatreDimension.rowNum)">
            <td id={{row}}_{{seat}} *ngFor="let seat of createRange(seats.theatreDimension.seatNumInRow)">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to access table *td* element from angular 2  *.ts* file. Here are functions:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getSeats();
}

getSeats() {
    this.cinemaService.getAllSeats(this.repertoire.id).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.seats = data.json();   
            this.setReservedSeats();
        }
    )
}
setReservedSeats() {
    this.seats.reservedSeats.forEach(seat => {
            let cssSeatId = seat.rowNumReserved + "_" + seat.seatNumInRowResereved;
            document.getElementById(cssSeatId).className += "reserved";
        }
    )
}
```

and after that I want dynamically to set *class* of every *td*, but I am getting this console error in my browser:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null**

Just to note once again that I generate *td* ids dynamically. They are in form *rowNum_cellNum*.

I am getting this object from api.

```
{
"theatreDimension": {
    "rowNum": 17,
    "seatNumInRow": 20
},
"reservedSeats": [
    {
        "rowNumReserved": 9,
        "seatNumInRowResereved": 19
    },
    {
        "rowNumReserved": 2,
        "seatNumInRowResereved": 4
    },
    {
        "rowNumReserved": 15,
        "seatNumInRowResereved": 15
    }
]
```

}

I am using theatreDimension to make table. Then I try to make reserved seats from reservedSeats array with red background (reserved)

How I can access td elements from angular 2 and solve this issue?

Comment: what is the value of `cssSeatId` in your code ? have you checked it?

Comment: In this forEach I am forming cssSeatId correctly, so in form rowNum_seatNum: 9_19, 2_4, 15_15. That is according with the JSON that I got from api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of accessing the DOM directly, you should try using the `ngClass` directive to set the class:

```
<td [ngClass]="{'reserved': isReserved(row, seat)}" id={{row}}_{{seat}} *ngFor="let seat of createRange(seats.theatreDimension.seatNumInRow)">

</td>
```

You can then implement the `isReserved(row, seat)` function, and if it returns true, it will apply the `reserved` class.

```
isReserved(rowNum: number, seatNum: number) {
    return this.seats.reservedSeats.some((r) => r.rowNumReserved === rowNum && r.seatNumInRowResereved === seatNum);
}
```

Comment: I implemented

'isReserved(rowNum: number, seatNum: number) {
        this.seats.reservedSeats.forEach(seat => {
                if (seat.rowNumReserved == rowNum && seat.seatNumInRowResereved == seatNum) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        )
    }'

and used 
[ngClass]="{'reserved': isReserved(row, seat)}"

but no result.

Comment: That's because your `isReserved` function doesnt return any value. Your return statement is within a callback, so that only returns from the callback

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please?
How should my function look like?

Comment: How can I set class of td on click on that td?

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, in order to get the element by ID, you need to do so after the page has been renedered. Use the function ngAfterViewInit(). You will need to remove the call to setReservedSeats() from getSeats().

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getSeats();
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.setReservedSeats();
}
```

However, I would suggest going a different route. You can set the style of the  element based on whether or not the seat has been reserved. Assuming you have some sort of "reserved" flag on the seat object you can do something like this:

```
<td id={{row}}_{{seat}} 
    [ng-class]="{'reserved' : seat.researved}"
    *ngFor="let seat of createRange(seats.theatreDimension.seatNumInRow)">
</td>
```